# how to load or add js before require js in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, knockoutjs, requirejs

I am trying to override default_head_blocks.xml like below

**vendor\magento\module-theme\view\frontend\layout\default_head_blocks.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
* Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
* See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
        <css src="mage/calendar.css"/>
        <script src="requirejs/require.js"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="after.body.start">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Js\Components" name="head.components" as="components" template="Magento_Theme::js/components.phtml" before="-"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**app\design\frontend\Enterprise\Orange\Magento_Theme\layout\default_head_blocks.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
* Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
* See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/
-->

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
                <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
                                <link src="js/customercookie.js"/>
                                <link src="js/customercookie.js"/>
                                <link src="Orange_Webform::js/mnpform.js"/>
        <css src="mage/calendar.css"/>
        <css src="common-header/css/custom.css"/>
                                <script src="shm/shm.js"/>
                                <script src="common-header/js/custom.js"/>
        <script src="requirejs/require.js"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="after.body.start">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Js\Components" name="head.components" as="components" template="Magento_Theme::js/components.phtml" before="-"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Just I want to load shm/shm.js before requirejs/require.js

Please do the needfull

Comment: You need to make sure that your module loads before magento's so that your javscript is added first. E.g name your package AaEnterprise_Orange, with what you have it should work.

Comment: Can anyone answer this question?I have same concern....

Answer (score -2):

To load custom js before require.js than add custom js in below XML path

app\design\frontend\Enterprise\Orange\Magento_Theme\layout\override\base\default_head_blocks.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
   <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
                            <link src="js/customercookie.js"/>
                            <link src="js/customercookie.js"/>
                            <link src="Orange_Webform::js/mnpform.js"/>
    <css src="mage/calendar.css"/>
    <css src="common-header/css/custom.css"/>
                            <script src="shm/shm.js"/>
                            <script src="common-header/js/custom.js"/>
    <script src="requirejs/require.js"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <referenceContainer name="after.body.start">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Js\Components" name="head.components" as="components" template="Magento_Theme::js/components.phtml" before="-"/>
    </referenceContainer>
  </body>
</page>
```